# afex aov_ez ezANOVA discrepency

Tags: python, r, anova

I am trying to figure out why I am getting different results from the two pieces of code below (I am running it in a python notebook, if that makes a difference):

```
%Rpush df
%R my_anova <- ezANOVA(data = df, dv = dv1, between = .(group, site), wid=id)
%R print(my_anova)

%Rpush df
%R my_other_anova <- aov_ez("id","df1",df,between=c("group", "site"),anova_table=list(correction="none", es = "none"))
%R print (my_other_anova)
```

The first chunk of code results in:

```
Effect     df      MSE      F p.value
1            group 1, 286 13908.95 6.00 *     .01
2             site 3, 286 13908.95   0.34     .79
3       group:site 3, 286 13908.95   1.45     .23
```

And the second results in:

```
Effect DFn DFd        F             p p<.05        ges
1            group   1 286 6.485729 0.01139854     * 0.02217451
2             site   3 286 3.101433 0.02708813     * 0.03150750
3       group:site   3 286 1.448696 0.22883103       0.01496865
```

I'm not sure as to why these would be different, any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: You should indicate in your question which packages these functions are from.

Answer (score 2):

`ezANOVA` uses type 2 sums of squares, `aov_ez` uses type 3. see `?ezANOVA` and `?aov_ez`.